# Find the documents which have element in proper "dateTime" format

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am trying the following query in marklogic-9:

```
cts:element-value-match(xs:QName("cd:modificationDate"), "[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T[H01]:[m01]:[s01].000Z", ("type=dateTime","timezone=TZ"))
```

to achieve this, but this gives me the following error:

```
[1.0-ml] XDMP-ARG: cts:element-value-match(xs:QName("cd:modificationDate"), "[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T[H01]:[m01]:[s01].000Z", ("type=dateTime", "timezone=TZ")) -- arg2 is invalid
```

What i want to do is to find out all those documents which conforms to this specific pattern of `dateTime`. We have a date-range index on this element - `modificationDate`.

How best can we do this using marklogic and xquery api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cts:element-value-match` is really only useful on string range indexes and even there it only takes simple wildcards (`*` and `?`), not general regular expressions or date formats.

If your range index is a dateTime range index, then every value must conform to the proper `xs:dateTime` format, so this query would tell you nothing.

This will give you a list of all the URIs where you have a valid dateTime in that element:

```
cts:uris("", (),
    cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("modificationDate"), ">", xs:dateTime("0001-01-01T00:00:00"))
)
```

Comment: Not exactly what i was looking for, but it solved the problem which i was facing :)